# Auto-Reboot on Kernel BUG (not tainted, “fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed”)

Tags: debian, xenserver, debian-wheezy, linux-kernel, kernel-panic

I'm running a sometimes highly loaded Debian 7 VM with the latest 3.2.x kernel on a XenServer 6.2 host.

Sometimes this VM runs into the following state:

- Ping is okay, All Services unreachable (including SSH)
- A message showing a trace + "kernel BUG" shows up
- Further below the error message “fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed” is shown

sysctl `kernel.panic=1` is already set. This has no effect in this case. The machine does not reboot.

How is is possible to let the machine reboot itself after such a fault (since this is no OOPS, right?)?

Ideally before rebooting a sync of filesystems and ro mount would be nice...

I know about SysRQ but I'm searching a solution which does work without manual intervention.

Thank you! :)[image]

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: @MarkAvenius I think in the end I stayed with kernel.panic setting and it worked somehow. I don't find it in my current sysctl config actually anymore. Didn't kernel.panic work for you either as it seemed to me 2y ago?

Comment: This is reappearing to me unfortunately... No fix found still @MarkAvenius

Comment: Can you get more of the error than is shown in your screenshot? Check your logs, or try increasing the screen resolution.